# Inserting and deleting Data using Entity Framework Issue

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to link my data to asp.net mvc application.
The weird part is that I can read the records normally using the below GetALL function but none of the Insert and Delete are working. Is there any reason for that? I am wondering if there is any restriction on the database and how to fix it if any? Note that I am getting no error however it is saying create is successful and delete is successful as well.

```
 public IEnumerable<tbl_Category> GetALL()
        {
            return db.tbl_Category.ToList();
        }
        public tbl_Category GetByID(int Id)
        {
            return db.tbl_Category.Find(Id);
        }
        public void Insert(tbl_Category cat)
        {
            db.tbl_Category.Add(cat);
        }
        public void Delete(int Id)
        {
            tbl_Category cat = db.tbl_Category.Find(Id);
            db.tbl_Category.Remove(cat);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to call the SubmitChanges() / SaveChanges() on the data context.